# Why isn't the graphics object rendering the image?

Tags: p5.js

Background: I am trying to program the wave function collapse algorithm

I have a tile class which contains an image object.
When a condition is false - I create a new tile instance with the same image but just rotated x amount. The image is not being rendered in the graphics object.

I have two images (blank and up), the up image will have 3 variants (right, down, left).

---

```
    getImageRotate(numRotate) {
    let newImg = {};

    newImg = createGraphics(this.W, this.H);
    newImg.imageMode(CENTER);
    newImg.translate(this.W / 2, this.H / 2);
    newImg.rotate(HALF_PI * numRotate);
    
    newImg.image(this.IMG, 0, 0);

    return newImg;
}
```

[This is what is being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK1zd.png)

---

```
    getImageRotate(numRotate) {
    let newImg = {};

    newImg = createGraphics(this.W, this.H);
    newImg.imageMode(CENTER);
    newImg.translate(this.W / 2, this.H / 2);
    newImg.rotate(HALF_PI * numRotate);
    newImg.background(0);
    newImg.triangle(-20, 0, 20, 0, 0, 20);

    return newImg;
}
```

[Here I am drawing a triangle instead of rendering the image and it works, thus this means the graphics object is being rendered, just not the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj5Z9.png)

---

Preload:

```
function preload() {
  /* SETUP VARIABLES */
  const PATH = "images/";
  const EXT = ".png";
  const NUM_IMG = 2;
  const DIM = createVector(100, 100);

  let img = {};
  let tileIndx = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_IMG; i++) {

    img = loadImage(`${PATH}${i}${EXT}`);
    tiles[tileIndx] = new Tile(img, EDGES[i], DIM.x, DIM.y);

    addRotationVarients();

    tileIndx++;

  }

  function addRotationVarients() {

    const ORIGINAL_TILE = tiles[tileIndx];;
    let newEdges = {};
    let newImg = {};

    for (let numRotate = 1; numRotate < 4; numRotate++) {

      newEdges = ORIGINAL_TILE.getEdgeRotate(numRotate);

      if (!arrayEqual(ORIGINAL_TILE.EDGES, newEdges)) {

        newImg = ORIGINAL_TILE.getImageRotate(numRotate);
    
        tileIndx++;
        tiles[tileIndx] = new Tile(newImg, newEdges, DIM);

      }
    }
  }

  function arrayEqual(arr1, arr2) {

    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
      return false;
    }

    for (let n = 0; n < arr1.length; n++) {
      if (arr1[n] != arr2[n]) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

---

Drawing:

```
  function drawGrid() {

  const W = canvasWidth / DIM;
  const H = canvasHeight / DIM;

  for (let r = 0; r < DIM; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < DIM; c++) {

      const INDX = r + c * DIM;
      const CELL = this.grid[INDX];

      if (CELL.isCollapsed) {

        try {
          image(tiles[CELL.options[0]].img, c * W, r * H, W, H);
        }
        catch (ERR) {
          console.log(ERR);
        }

      } else {

        push();
        stroke(255, 100);
        fill(0);
        rect(c * W, r * H, W, H);
        pop();

      }

    }
  }
}
```

This video will give an idea of what I would like to accomplish. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI_y2GAlQFM&t=2705s) @ 41:13

I have tried the following...

Rotating the image inside sketch.js-preload(). This did not work and gave the exact same outcome.

Rotating the image inside sketch.js-draw(). This worked, but I will not work with the rest of the program and will waste a lot of computational time.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)   I will not check which images contain an image, and which ones do contain code....

Comment: Rather than EDIT: SOLVED, please write a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I just moved the logic for adding the tiles to the setup function instead of preload.